# Restrict SSH login to public key from public networks, but allow password from internal networks

Tags: ssh, password, public-key

Assume UserA is allowed to log in by SSH to a server from public networks as well as from within private ones.

Is there any option to restrict password-enabled logins to the private networks while enforcing public key authentication for the rest of the world?

What I have so far in my config

```
AllowUsers root@10.0.0.2 root@10.0.0.1 usera
```

How can I enable usera to log in from usera@10.0.0/24 by public key or password, and enforce pubic key login for usera from any other network?

Does something imilar to the following work?  What is the exact notation syntax?

```
# no password login from the public
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# allow password login from private network
Match Users usera@10.0.0/24 root@10.0.0/24
   PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Thanks for any enlightenment.

PS: Reason for this setup is to enable password-login from within the internal network as a measure of last resort if anything else fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is close.  I think what you want is

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes

AuthenticationMethods publickey

Match Address 10.0.0.0/24
AuthenticationMethods publickey password
```

You can find the details in `man sshd_config`.